# I have three arrays of numbers, let's say A, B, and C, and I'm trying to find out what combination of A and B come closest to the C array

Tags: python

For instance if my numbers were: A=[1,2,3] B=[4,5,6] and C=[5,10,11] then the closest function I can get to would be 2A+B. Any idea about what kind of optimization pattern would be needed for something like this?

Comment: Are you trying to find two scalars a, b such that when multiplied by A & B, we minimize the difference with array C?  Are a, b restricted to integers only or can they be floats?

Comment: Basically yes, I'm trying to minimize: C- f(A)- g(B). (This function can take any form, doesn't have to be additive) And yes, a and b can be floats

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis, probably simple linear regression is what you need - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find real values p and q such that the distance between pA + qB and C is minimal.

pA + qB = pi + 2pj + 3pk + 4qi + 5qj + 6qk = i(p + 4q) + j(2p + 5q) + k(3p + 6q)

The distance is given by:
f(p,q) = √((p + 4q - 5)² + (2p + 5q - 10)² + (3p + 6q - 11)²)

Take its partial derivatives and find the local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This can be set up as a system of linear equations and solved using numpy

```
import numpy as np

A=[1,2,3] 
B=[4,5,6]
C=[5,10,11]

# Set up as a system of linear equations to solve with 
# min mean square error, i.e. find x, y such that:
# Solve Ax + By = C
# As linear equations become
# [A; B] [x y] = C
# With M = [A; B] we have (i.e. A, B are the column vectors of M)
M = np.matrix((list(zip(A, B))))

# Find Least Square Error Solution
sol = np.linalg.lstsq(M, C, rcond=None)[0] # Solve for [x y]
print("Solution (Least Min Square Error\n", sol) # [2.11111111 0.88888889]

approx = np.dot(M, sol)  
print("approximation\n", approx)  # [[ 5.66666667  8.66666667 11.66666667]]
```